# SocketIO Client C++. Задать transports при подключении

Tags: c++, socket.io, socketio-client

Использую для подключения к сокету библиотеку socket.io-client-cpp (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp).

```
auto m_ws = new sio::client();
m_ws->connect("https://api.forkdelta.com");
```

При коннекте происходит постоянное переподключение с ошибкой:

```
[2020-03-25 11:24:21] [connect] Successful connection
[2020-03-25 11:24:21] [error] Server handshake response error: websocketpp.processor:20 (Invalid HTTP status.)
```

Такая же ситуация и на nodejs

```
// не работает
var socket = SocketIO.connect('https://api.forkdelta.com');
```

Но когда я добавлю `transports` - такой код на nodejs будет работать отлично

```
// работает
var socket = SocketIO.connect('https://api.forkdelta.com', {
    transports: ['websocket']
});
```

Мои попытки повторить это на C++ оказались неудачными

```
// не работает
m_ws->connect("https://api.forkdelta.com", {}, {{"transports", "websocket"}});
m_ws->connect("https://api.forkdelta.com", {{"transports", "websocket"}});
```

Как задать параметр `transports` на C++?

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что С++ API  в точности воспроизводит API node? Рекомендую почитать доку и примеры в приведенной вами ссылке.

Comment: @JK_Action потому что в C++ API этот параметр явно не задается, а при его отсутствии в NodeJS возникает похожая ситуация. Код взят из примеров, доку изучаю, пока без результатов. В исходниках ``sio_client_impl.cpp`` обнаружил создание ссылки ``/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket``. Получается, все уже сделано за меня. Проблема в другом

Comment: @trsv у вас получилось решить проблему?